# subtitle on article

Tags: math-mode, titles

I have gone through all the questions and none seem to work or are the same as mine.

I am using LaTeX for my math degree assignments.

My code is this

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\title{\Large{\textbf{Course ID - Module Name}}}
\subtitle{Module Number}
\author{Name -  {\text{ID}}}
\date{}
```

Anyone with any ideas. I keep getting undefined control sequence

Comment: `article` doesn't have a `\subtitle` command just use `Course ID - Module Name}\\Module number`

Comment: I hardly know of any classes that supports a subtitle, article certainly do not. Btw: `\Large`  is a switch, it does not take any arguments.

Comment: Or if you want to use subtitle you can use the `scrartcl` class which is part of the KOMA script instead of `article` class

Comment: What is `\author{Name -  {\text{ID}}}` (especially teh `\text{}`) supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

With the `titling` package, I could insert a `\subtitle` command for `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}

\makeatletter
\def\@subtitle{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\subtitle given}}
\def\subtitle#1{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}
\title{Course ID - Module Name}
\subtitle{Module Number}
\author{Name - {ID}}
\date{}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\Large\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par
       \mdseries \@subtitle
      \par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}%\@subtitle\par
\preauthor{\begin{center}%
\large \lineskip 0.5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}}
\predate{\begin{center}\large}
\postdate{\par\end{center}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]